# gcc generate .o file instead of executable

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc

I'm trying to debug claws-mail notification plugin, I have code like this:

```
#include "notification_indicator.h"
#include "notification_prefs.h"
#include "notification_core.h"

#include "folder.h"
#include "common/utils.h"

#include <messaging-menu.h>
#include <unity.h>

#define CLAWS_DESKTOP_FILE "claws-mail.desktop"

#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
  GList *cur_mb;
  gint total_message_count;


  total_message_count = 0;
  /* check accounts for new/unread counts */
  for(cur_mb = folder_get_list(); cur_mb; cur_mb = cur_mb->next) {
    Folder *folder = cur_mb->data;
    NotificationMsgCount count;

    if(!folder->name) {
      printf("Notification plugin: Warning: Ignoring unnamed mailbox in indicator applet\n");
      continue;
    }
    gchar *id = folder->name;
    notification_core_get_msg_count_of_foldername(folder->name, &count);
    printf("%s: %d\n", folder->name, count.unread_msgs);
  }
}
```

and I'm compiling it with this command:

```
gcc  -I/home/kuba/Pobrane/claws-mail-3.13.2/src/
     -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0/
     -I/usr/include/cairo/
     -I/usr/include/pango-1.0
     -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include/
     -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/
     -I/usr/include/atk-1.0/
     -I/home/kuba/Pobrane/claws-mail-3.13.2/src/common
     -I/home/kuba/Pobrane/claws-mail-3.13.2/src/gtk
     -I/usr/include/messaging-menu/
     -I/usr/include/unity/unity/
     -I/usr/include/dee-1.0/
     -I/usr/include/libdbusmenu-glib-0.4/
     -c `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` test.c
```

but gcc create object file test.o instead of a.out how can I create executable file? I'm running this on Xubuntu.

Comment: That's the whole point of the `-c` option. It tells it to just create an object file instead of linking into an executable. If you don't want that, don't use the option.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Remove the `-c` option from the commandline (which generates the object file instead of executable).

From `man gcc`:

> -c
> Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link.  The linking stage simply is not done.  The ultimate output is in the form
> of an object file for each source file.

Examples:

To generate an object file (`.o' file):

```
gcc -c test.c
```

To generate an executable:

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

(if you omit the `-o test`, it'd generate `a.out` as executable by convention).

Comment: why you don't give an example like `gcc -c file2alias.c` * 
uf I was looking the way to generate .o instead the executable, sorry

Comment: @Sérgio Because the question wasn't that! I've now add a couple of examples anyway.

Comment: now, I could change my vote :) , thank you