# How can I make a .o with gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I tried with:
`gcc file.c` and `gcc file.c -o New_file` and both give the same `.exe` file. I only need the `.o`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gcc generate .o file instead of executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027227/gcc-generate-o-file-instead-of-executable)

Comment: just use `-c` for _compile only, don't link_ option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command "man gcc" to find out more about the gcc command.

To answer your question though: gcc file.c **-c** -o output.o

Comment: What does "Is that the Machine Code?" mean? This answer answers your question about how to get a `.o` from a `.c` file using `gcc`.